# Is it like If I am using Twilio Flex, then I only have to customize the UI and build the API from scratch?

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

If I am using Twilio flex then do I need to build the API from scratch and can customize the UI according to me.

Means can I build API of my own? And I don't need to build my own UI, just customize that which is provided by flex.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking here. Twilio Flex connects the Twilio APIs to a customisable interface. You don't need to build an API yourself.

Comment: We can customize interface that is understood. Is it possible to build our own API and connect it to customisable interface alongside Twilio APIs?

Comment: I believe he is asking how we would authenticate with custom built apis securely perhaps using a unified Auth token?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you are building with [Flex](https://www.twilio.com/flex) you can absolutely add your own endpoints so you can call other services from the UI. I've done this before using Twilio Functions, but as long as the URL can respond to HTTP requests you can host it anywhere.

This is a good way to customise Flex to extend it outside of the Twilio API.

Comment: So, can I use it to make outbound calls through Twilio? But as of now Twilio flex doesn't support outbound calls.

Comment: [That is correct](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010789173-How-do-I-Make-Outbound-Calls-with-Twilio-Flex-)

Comment: Means it is not possible to make outbound calls with Twilio flex right now. Ok thanks @philnash

Comment: It is as you said, Flex doesn't support outbound calls out the box, however you can indeed build that in yourself if you want to.